# Python list see if contains consecutive numbers but avoid the adjacent/next duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to test if a list contains consecutive integers. But if the next element is duplicate it show avoid it.

For e.g.

```
raw_list_1 = [400, 401, 402] # this is valid
raw_list_2 = [400, 401, 403] # this is in-valid
raw_list_3 = [400, 401, 401, 401, 402, 403] # this is valid
```

in the case of **raw_list_3** we got the pattern where number can repeat in sequential manner.

my code

```
raw_list_1 = [400, 401, 402] # this is valid
raw_list_2 = [400, 401, 403] # this is in-valid
raw_list_3 = [400, 401, 401, 401, 402, 403] # this is valid
is_valid_list = sorted(raw_list_3) == list(range(min(raw_list_3), max(raw_list_3)+1))
print(is_valid_list)
False
#################
```

Comment: `sorted(set(raw_list))` should work and remove duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: @luk2302 it has some pattern, which i need to keep it in mind.

Comment: @luk2302 the upcoming element can be duplicate, will it satisfy this condition

Comment: Then you a) would need to provide more examples and state clearly where your code fails for what reason, b) look at the linked post which talks about retaining order, and c) maybe do not sort the list in the first place!?

Comment: What do you mean, "some pattern"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optimisation of your method would be to just check that the difference between the first element and the last element, rather than actually generate the list:

```
sorted_uniques = sorted(set(raw_list))
is_valid_list = sorted_uniques[-1] - sorted_uniques[0] == len(sorted_uniques) - 1
```

If the sorting trick is not to be used, you can check the difference between consecutive elements:

```
is_valid_list = all(0 <= y - x <= 1 for x, y in zip(raw_list, raw_list[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first derivative is always in `{0, 1}` the list is valid.

```
import numpy as np

def is_valid(arr_like):
    return np.isin(np.diff(arr_like), [0,1]).all()

is_valid(raw_list_1), is_valid(raw_list_2), is_valid(raw_list_3)

#OUTPUT:
#(True, False, True)
```

If you are sure that all your lists are monotonic not decreasing you could optimize the function in the following way:

```
def is_valid(arr_like):
    return (np.diff(arr_like)<=1).all()
```